# audio, LTspice - crossover simulation problems

Tags: audio, ltspice

I am currently trying to design an x-over. The response of what I have spiced does not correlate to what I though would happen. Have I made any obvious mistakes?

I want a Sallen-key HP/LP. That crosses over at around 120hz with a gap between the Hp & Lp points because of the driver units being mismatched.

Any thing obvious I’ve done wrong?

[image]

Comment: What power supply are you using?

Comment: Why we have got to use is a 18v DC adaptor stolen from something else. So I’m splitting it with two 10k resistors and off of the middle tap I have an op amp buffer and between the three taps I have two 100nF caps for smoothing.

Answer (score 2):

> Any thing obvious I’ve done wrong?

I'm not ruling out other issues but you haven't got ground connected properly: -

[image]

You also need to put power rails on the op-amp.

Comment: Thanks Andy!  An obvious mistake....  Now working the way i expected.